# Concatenate two DataFrames into one MultiIndex sharing the same DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I could concatenate two DataFrames df1 & df2 into one df but I somehow could not get the "stack" structure that I need - see attached image.

How do I get df1 & df2 to combine to share one DateTimeIndex like the one in a "stack" structure?

[image: df1 & df2]
[image: df]

Comment: What is desired output? if missing datetime in first level of Multiindex it is only display thing, really it is duplicated. You can check it if add `.reset_index()`

Comment: Do you need `.unstack()` ?

Comment: .stack() or .unstack() results in a Series; I need a DataFrame with MultiIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAPL':[1,3,4],
                   'GOOG_L':[6,7,8]}, index=pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=3))
print (df)
            AAPL  GOOG_L
2012-01-01     1       6
2012-01-02     3       7
2012-01-03     4       8

df1 = df.stack().to_frame('col')
print (df1)
                   col
2012-01-01 AAPL      1
           GOOG_L    6
2012-01-02 AAPL      3
           GOOG_L    7
2012-01-03 AAPL      4
           GOOG_L    8

df2 = df.unstack().to_frame('col')
print (df2)
                   col
AAPL   2012-01-01    1
       2012-01-02    3
       2012-01-03    4
GOOG_L 2012-01-01    6
       2012-01-02    7
       2012-01-03    8
```

Comment: Absolutely the swiftest solution ever! Thank you very much!